# Flask - Not allowed to load local resource - image issue

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I have the following code which generates the correct filepath for the images I have, it also populates them correctly inside the generated HTML in browser, but my browser refuses to load saying, that it is 'Not allowed to load local resource'.

This is the code I have:
Python3:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def main():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    
    #Defines what to do when the request is GET
    if request.method == 'GET':
        allPosts = c.execute('SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY time DESC')
        return render_template('index.html', allPosts = allPosts)

    #Defines what to do when the request is POST
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass

@app.route("/upload", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    #Define what to do if method is GET
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('upload.html')
#Define what to do if method is POST
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #Get the data from the form
        #image = request.files['image']
        username = request.form['username']
        title = request.form['nadpis']
        post = request.form['prispevok']
        
        #Get a random ID of post
        randomIdOfPost = random.randrange(99999999)
        
        #Get current timestamp
        actualTime = datetime.now()
        actualTimeForInsertingIntoDB = str(actualTime.day) + '.' + str(actualTime.month) + '.' + str(actualTime.year) + ' ' + str(actualTime.hour) + ':' + str(actualTime.minute) + ':' + str(actualTime.second)
        
        if 'image' not in request.files:
            flash('No image part')
            return redirect('/upload', code=302)
        image = request.files['image']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit an empty part without filename
        if image.filename == '':
            flash('No selected image')
            return redirect('/upload', code=302)
        if image and allowed_file(image.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(image.filename)
            filename = str(randomIdOfPost) + '_' + filename
            image.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            imageName = str(filename)
        
        
        #Save the post into DB
        data = [(randomIdOfPost, actualTimeForInsertingIntoDB, username, title, post, imageName)]
        c.executemany('INSERT INTO posts VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)', data)
        conn.commit()
      
        return redirect('/', code=302)
```

HTML:

```
{% for row in allPosts %}
    <div class="container-fluid" align="center">
    <span class="badge badge-info">#{{ row[0] }} / Pridané dňa {{ row[1] }}<br>používateľom {{ row[2] }}</span>
    <h6>{{ row[3] }}</h6>
    <p>{{ row[4] }}</p>
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='{{ row[5] }}') }}" alt="my text">
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>   
{% endfor %}
```

On top of my Python3 code I also have:

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.getcwd() + r'\static'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=os.getcwd(), static_folder=os.getcwd() + r'\static')
#Set the route to the static folder (folder containing css stylesheet)
app._static_folder = os. getcwd() + "\\css"
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
```

The only issue I have is, that **my browser does not allow me to show the images that someone uploaded**.

All the help is much appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

```
{% for row in allPosts %}
    <div class="container-fluid" align="center">
    <span class="badge badge-info">#{{ row[0] }} / Pridané dňa {{ row[1] }}<br>používateľom {{ row[2] }}</span>
    <h6>{{ row[3] }}</h6>
    <p>{{ row[4] }}</p>
    
    <!-- I tried both <img> tags below, none of them works.. -->
    <img src="{{ row[5] }}" alt="my text">
    <!-- <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='{{ row[5] }}') }}" alt="my text"> -->
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>   
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please post the complete error message, incl line numbers

Comment: Flask does not give any errors, it's only in console of my browser that I am able to see that it says: Not allowed to load local resource. Then, where my <img> tags are, only a 'broken image' is visible...

Comment: Please show me the HTML source code. Especially the part where the img tags get rendered. Please put this above in the question, properly formatted as code

Comment: @J.G. I have added the HTML code where the images get populated using Jinja2. It's under the EDIT 1 in my question above.
Thank you

Comment: Suggestion: Since it looks like you're on Windows, don't use `\` with file paths in your code. Use `os.path.join` et al. exclusively.  And you probably don't want to be doing `app._static_folder = os. getcwd() + "\\css"`

Comment: @DaveW.Smith I am not sure I get what you mean. I am not  using ‘with file paths’ in my code anywhere. I have changed now the static to be \\static at the end instead of \\css. Thanks

Comment: @rogaloo please add rendered HTML - that is when no more Jinja syntax is left, but when Flask renders the page and you can view it in the browser. As Dave hinted, the problem seems to be when building the path names.

Comment: `static_folder=os.getcwd() + r'\static'` embeds a `\\` when constructing a file path. (Looks like my previous attempt at saying that ran afoul of markdown.)

Comment: My rendered HTML looks like this: 
`<div class="container-fluid" align="center">
 <span class="badge badge-info">#60215631 / Pridané dňa 21.7.2020 8:27:20<br>používateľom myUsername1</span>
 <h6>some text</h6>
 <p>some text2</p>
<img src="c:\Users\rogaloo\Downloads\rogaloo - Programming projects\Programming projects\Python projects\imageboard\static\images\60215631_IMG_2450.jpg" alt="my text">
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>`

Comment: Additionally, this is exactly the error that I get in my browser when I open console:
`Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/rogaloo/Downloads/rogaloo%20-%20Programming%20projects/Programming%20projects/Python%20projects/imageboard/static/images/60215631_IMG_2450.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='{{ row[5] }}') }}" alt="my text">
```

Should probably be:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=row[5]) }}" alt="my text">
```

Comment: This worked out. I actually changed it to: `<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/'+row[5]) }}" alt="my text">` and it worked
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You really need to view the source code in the browser, to see what img paths are rendering.  Don't nest curly braces.  Try this to see if it's a path issue:

```
<img src="/path/to/static/{{ row[5] }}" alt="my text">
```

You want to unnest the vars, like:

```
{{ url_for('static', filename=row[5]) }}
```